# Launching iTunes Store within iPhone app using PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, cordova

When I use itms://.itunes.apple.com/us/album/speak-now/id399727924 it works fine in xcode.
But, I'm trying to use this in phonegap and external linking is not working.. is there a way to launch itunes within app.. ex: _webapp?
thanks,
jad

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

iPhone will recognize an URL to the iTunes store and open it with the proper app.

try to open the following url using an iOS device: http://itunes.apple.com/au/album/speak-now-single/id396131841

On your URL, there is a dot (.) before itunes, maybe your problem is this.